# Reconcile two datasets/collections when number of reconciling combinations is unknown

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm

So I work as a consultant doing accounting.  One of my tasks is to reconcile transactions between data sets.  One-to-one matching between the collections is pretty easy to solve, programatically.  I bascially dumped the data into two separate arrays and started checking for matches using nested for-loops.
My question is about how reconcile transactions when the number of transactions in either data set isn't known until run-time.  Further, the sums of the transactions have to be equal on both sides.
Ie.

```
DataSet #1    DataSet #2
A/%/k  $11    A/%/k  $22
A/%/k  $11    A/%/k  $33
A/%/k  $11
A/%/k  $11
A/%/k  $11
```

Above, don't be confused about (A), (%), or (k).  These are just identifying primary keys, if you will.  Ie.  They are matching contract numbers, invoice numbers, etc.  What is important is that in Dataset#1, 5 transactions total $55.  In Dataset#2, 2 transactions total $55.  The two sets reconcile.  Theoretically, you could have n Choose r number of transactions, whose sum on in Set#1 equals the sum in Set#2.  Less abstract, you could have 8 transactions in Set#1 whose sum equals 3 transactions in Set#2.  (8C3 = 56, btw)

Does anyone have any thoughts about an algorithm and/or array or other kind of data structure, where all possible combinations of sums are checked against the other collection?  Is there something in a library out there that could help?  My thoughts harken to recursive algorithms that calculate factorials to solve such a problem but once the combinatorics are calculated-- what then??  How do I calculate all 56 sums (see above)?  Really, there are X sums.

Again, the total matching number of transactions won't be known until run-time.  One last challenge is that I'd like to do this in VBA/Excel.  That's where my data lie and that's where my employer will support a technical solution.  Sorry, I cannot program in Python nor is it technically feasible where I work.  Also, apologies for not displaying code, as I have no code written yet.

Comment: Formatting issue:  D#1($22,$33). D#2($11, $11, $11, $11, $11)

Comment: What are reasonable maximum numbers for the individual and summed transactions in your real-world data?

Comment: Seems a little like a knapsack problem (or, a series of knapsack problems) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem   I suspect it will be relatively complex to write a VBA solution, and performace may be quite poor depending on how much entries you have for each matching set of data.  See also - http://onlinedigeditions.com/publication/?i=265838&article_id=2060675&view=articleBrowser

Comment: I'd say that there would probably be no more than 10 transactions on each side that can be uniquely identified.  Same for the second dataset.  Can't say for sure, but definitely not more than 20.  That'd be rare.

Comment: This would be outside of my ability, particularly if you don't expect to always get exact concurrence between the two datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Before we even get into programming, this seems more a problem in sets, best solved with SQL back in the database if any, or a pivot table in Excel.

If you put dataset 1 and 2 together into one long table, (you may need to add a column to identify a row as 1 or 2) and use THAT as the source of a pivot table ... you're done.

Have the pivot table sum up the amounts broken down by that primary key first, then the dataset ID second, so that (say) credits and debits on PO# 123987 are right beside each other.

Then VBA can look for differences; the pivot table objects allow selecting all the "credit/debit" cell pairs for each ID as one range, and you could impose some hairy conditional format to highlight the non-matches, or write a FOR EACH loop through the range looking for them procedurally.

I have done a very simple little example of your problem as I understand it, using a few dozen "credits" (dataset 1) and "debits" that sum to the same, always with different record counts, in a few cases, and have a discrepancy in one case.  The "Basic" sheet shows the two datasets, then a third table which is just the two combined.   The pivot table that uses that as a source is beside it.

Sheet #2, "Negatives" is a copy of the whole problem but with the transaction amounts for "debits" set as negative numbers.  That means the sum for each ID is zero if there is reconcilation.   More pivot table rules can then be set to only show ID numbers where the sum is non-zero, giving a report only of discrepancies.  But for the example, all are shown.

If this seems the right approach, we could get into how you could make a pivot table with VBA and search it for discrepancies.  Note the nice Pivot Table trick that if you click on the "100" discrepancy number, it makes a temp sheet with JUST the records for that sum on it, and you can see all the credits and debits for PO# 67890 all summarized.

Ummm...new around here...not sure if stackexchange provides a place to upload example spreadsheets to.  I have stored it here:

http://brander.ca/stackexchange/Pivot_Table_Example.xlsx

...and can leave it there for years.

Comment: Hi Roy.  Thanks for your answer.  Only problem is that there are thousands of rows.  And, what if there are two more transactions that line-up in dataset #2, for example.  When you sum up all the transactions identified by a primary key, there may be NON-reconciling transactions which introduce noise into the dataset.  Right?? Add one more transaction to D#2 for $40 and the total is $95.  I guess I'd have to see what your solution would be on a sheet.

Comment: Thousands of rows are no problem for Excel on any modern machine; neither are tens of thousands, for that matter.  I suppose I can drum up an example that might clarify this for you and perhaps give you a basis to explain "non-reconciling transactions" by adding one to the example.   Back in a few hours.

Comment: The answer has been edited for more detail, and an example posted.  Just post here again if I've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I see what you were trying to do with the Pivot table and that gives you totals for debits and credits, which is nice information to see.  However, I am looking more to write a script which identifies which totals and transactional information can be offset in column with another column of opposing data.  Your example would point to which columns can be added together to reconcile and leave other non-reconciling transactions alone.

Comment: Clearly I don't understand the problem, then.  I'd understood the value in the one dataset would be offset by values in the other dataset.   So I nicknamed them credits and debits and summed up both to see if they offset exactly or not.   If that's not the problem you need solved then I suppose I need an example to understand the problem and take another shot at it.

Comment: Hi Roy. Thanks for taking a stab at my question  and the problem. No doubt, pivot tables would work if you categorize by a primary key and sum up the values, you could see where one dataset doesnt equal the other, for the distinct key. The fault lies with me and my description.  1. theres thousands of lines of data. 2. one dataset may include invoices that the other dataset does not. I want to tie out and format those that do reconcile. ignore those that need research. I want to tie out those that do reconcile though.